# Rationale for Eigen API for Matrix with Scalar operations

Tags: c++, eigen3

Consider the following code:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

using Matrix = Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>;

Matrix func1(const Matrix& mat) { return mat + 0.5; }
Matrix func2(const Matrix& mat) { return mat / 0.5; }
```

`func1()` does not compile; you need to replace `mat` with `mat.array()` in the function body to fix it ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65455597/adding-scalar-to-eigen-matrix-vector)). However, `func2()` **does** compile as-is.

My question has to do with **why** the API is designed this way. Why is addition-with-scalar and division-by-scalar treated differently? What problems would arise if the following method is added to the `Matrix` class, and why haven't those problems arisen already for the `operator/` method?:

```
auto operator+(Scalar s) const { return this->array() + s; }
```

Comment: I assume because scalar multiplication is part of the [basic operations on matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Addition,_scalar_multiplication,_and_transposition) while scalar addition is not. As for why it is defines as such, and why the operator isn't added just for practicality, I cannot say. I certainly stumbled over this myself multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a mathematics perspective, a scalar added to a matrix "should" be the same as adding the scalar *only to the diagonal*. That is, a math text would usually use `M + 0.5` to mean `M + 0.5I`, for `I` the identity matrix. There are many ways to justify this. For example, you can appeal to the analogy `I = 1`, or you can appeal to the desire to say `Mx + 0.5x = (M + 0.5)x` whenever `x` is a vector, etc.

Alternatively, you *could* take `M + 0.5` to add `0.5` to every element. This is what you think is right if you don't think of matrices from a "linear algebra mindset" and treat them as just collections (arrays) of numbers, where it is natural to just "broadcast" scalar operations.

Since there are multiple "obvious" ways to handle `+` between a scalar and a matrix, where someone expecting one may be blindsided by the other, it is a good idea to do as Eigen does and ban such expressions. You are then forced to signify what you want in a less ambiguous way.

The natural definition of `/` from an algebra perspective coincides with the array perspective, so no reason to ban it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. As a follow-up: some libraries (numpy, pytorch) define + as an element-wise operation. Was this decision controversial, or did it cause confusion? I can certainly see how numpy's broadcasting paradigm essentially forced their hand on this decision, but would be curious to see what the overall viewpoint on this is.

Comment: I might argue further that, given that `Eigen::Matrix` supports non-square matrices and matrices whose dimensions are specified at runtime, that *if* `operator+(Scalar)` is defined for runtime-square matrices, *then* that definition must "obviously" be consistent with its definition for runtime-non-square matrices. There is only one plausible definition of this operation for non-square matrices (element-wise). This to me makes it "obvious" that element-wise addition is the only plausible general definition of `Matrix + Scalar`.

Comment: @dshin That's *logical*, but that's certainly not *obvious*! Also, the mathematician can plausibly expect a "linear-algebra-respecting `+`" to work for compile-time square matrices, give a compiler error for compile-time rectangular ones, and either give a compiler error for dynamically sized matrices or give a runtime error for dynamically sized rectangular matrices.

Comment: @dshin If you want to have array-like `+Scalar` behavior, why don't you use `Eigen::Array` instead of `Eigen::Matrix`? The main difference will be that `Array * Array` also does element-wise products (you'd have to write `arr1.matrix() * arr2.matrix()` if you want a matrix-product).

Comment: @chtz Oh wow! I simply never knew this class existed. This looks quite like what I want. I presume there is no analog for `Eigen::Tensor`?

Comment: @dshin I never actively used the Tensor module, but I think it mostly does element-wise operations by default anyways (if it does not, maybe ask a new question for that).